# Console.log in render method shows state = true, but jsx shows false

Tags: react-native, jsx, lifecycle

- I have a list of items which I bring back from an API call in componentDidMount.
- Each item has a sublist, which I want to render conditionally if the item was clicked (as an accordion).
- To achieve this, in componentDidMount I setState with a ranges_status object with this initial form:

  ```
  key1: false,
  key2: false,
  ...
  ```
- Then in a callback function I set the clicked item to true, and the previously clicked to false (to render as an accordion).
- It all works perfect on console.log, but JSX just is not updating according to the values of the state, it just maintains the initial value I gave the state in componentDidMount.

Here is my code (summarized just to make the point):

```
class Hijos extends React.Component {

state = {
  ranges_status: {}
}

componentDidMount() {
    /* Here: API call and populate a ranges_status object with only 
    false values

    ranges_status: {
       'key1': false
       'key2': false
    }
    */

    /* set state */
    this.setState({ 
        ranges_status: ranges_status
    })
}


_handleOnPress = (clicked_key_range) => {

  /* Here I update the ranges_status object depending on which item was 
  clicked, so it can take a form like: 

  ranges_status: {
     'key1': true
     'key2': false
     'key3': false
  } */

  this.setState({ ranges_status: ranges_status })

}


render() {

const ranges_status = this.state.ranges_status

/* HERE I CONSOLE.LOG AND IT SHOWS IT EVERY TIME JUST HOW IT'S SUPPOSED 
TO BE, BUT THE JSX KEEPS SHOWING JUST THE INITIAL STATE VALUES (ALL 
FALSE) */

console.log("asdasdasd ", ranges_status)

return (
  <Container>
    <ViewsHeader title={'Hijos'} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      <BasicHorseData/>
    <Content>
        <List
            dataArray={listHijosByRange}
            renderRow={(item) =>
              <ConditionalItem   key_range={item.key_range} is_active={this.state.ranges_status[item.key_range]} handle_on_press={this._handleOnPress} />
            }>
        </List>
    </Content>

     <ViewsFooter navigation={this.props.navigation} />

  </Container>
)
}
}


const ConditionalItem = (props) => {

   const is_active = props.is_active
   const key_range = props.key_range

   /* This shows false all the time */
   console.log(is_active)

   return(
     <ListItem
       button={true}
       onPress={() => props.handle_on_press(key_range)}
     >
       {/* THIS SHOWS FALSE ALL THE TIME TOO (here is where the 
       contional rendering is supposed to be) */}
       <Text>{is_active.toString()}</Text>
     </ListItem>
   )
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `List` element you're using?  I'm guessing it is not rerendering because its dataArray has not changed.

Comment: @MikeM The List element I get it from the API call. The data array does not change indeed. But I just use it to access the keys, the ones I use to get the values of the ranges_status object (trues or falses), and based on those values I want to render conditionally.

Comment: did u use native-base?

Comment: @Adarsh yes all native base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the List componet is form `NativeBase` , if so , please check this link :https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/698

It may be an issue with "Dynamic List won't refresh when data refreshes "
As the developer from the NativeBase commends, use `FlatList` with `ListItem`.

and make sure you add

```
<FlatLsit
 extraData={this.state.ranges_status}  
 ...
/>
```

it will help to update data

Comment: thanks man! That was the problem! I switched to FlatList and it worked like this: 

<FlatList
    extraData={this.state}  
 ...
/>

it just has to be this.state ( https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html )

Comment: glad to hear, I think , if you put this.state in extraData - the list will rerender every time states update, and if you use this.state.ranges_status , List rerender only when ranges_status from the state updates, please check :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this inside ConditionalItem component.

```
const is_active = props.is_active
```

to this.

```
let is_active = props.is_active
```

const keyword prevent you to override the value inside is_active. try changing it to let keyword.  Hope it works!.